# MySQL query with Python all variables

Tags: python, mysql

Unfortunately I didn't find an answer to my question, so I try it here. I think it is pretty easy, but I just don't get it right. Since it is my first question here I hope I did it right.

I'm using Python 3.5 with MySql. I use the MySql connector module and have mysql-server installed and active. I want to generate a query dynamically with variables from user input. It's a simple program where I want to let the user edit table entries. It works with all cases like:
    SET title = %s
    or WHERE title = %s
But when I want to make the column name `title` a variable too, it gives an error (Here ('title') ad ('owner') are both from user input). The error is sent when executing the second `c.execute()` Block on the bottom of the code Block:

```
> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('title') = ('owner') WHERE id = ('4')' at line 1
```

the "title" is the column name of the table. So I want the user to select which column he wants to change, not only the values.
I just don't get the formatting of the first variable right. See the Code snippet below, it hopefully makes it clearer (the last 3 lines are the main focus here:

```
id_edit = input("Which Application do you want to change? (give Id): ")
id_edit = str(id_edit)

# field_edit is the word "Company" or "Title" for selecting the right column
old_field = input('Which field of Application "%s" do you want to change?: ' % (id_edit))
old_field = old_field.lower()

# new_field: Here the user gives the Input How he wants to name the Field instead
new_field = input('What should be the new value for the id "%s"?: ' % (old_field))    
new_field = new_field.lower()



 if old_field in table_names():
    # this works fine:        
    c.execute("UPDATE applications SET title = (%s) WHERE id = (%s)", (new_field, id_edit)) 
    # this is how I want it to work:
    c.execute("UPDATE applications SET (%s) = (%s) WHERE id = (%s)", (old_field, new_field, id_edit))
conn.commit()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you notice, field `title` itself has single inverted commas as `'title'`. Hence it is throwing error.

Comment: The notation is `SET x=y` not `SET x=(y)`. Adding more brackets fixes nothing.

Comment: You can't use parameter substitution for field names.